# Creating a shiny app to preform data manipulation

Tags: r, shiny

I have never made a shiny app through R before, but am attempting to make a very simple one. All I want this app to do is allow a user to upload a specific dataset from excel, then clean the data, and allow the user to download the cleaned dataset as a csv. I have already written the R code to perform all of the necessary steps to clean the data.

I just frankly have no idea where to start with regards to implementing the code as a Shiny app. Does anybody have any suggestions on where to begin? Tutorials or things of that nature would be great! Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: How about googling your own question title? this is among the top 3 results for me : [How to buld a shiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/build.html). You could also try out [flexdashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of resources out there on how to start.

I recommend you first read the introduction on [how to build a shiny app](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/build.html), and then look at some examples. What are [the basics](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/basics.html) of each app? What [other apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/) have been made before?

Once you built your app, you can even [deploy it for free](https://shiny.rstudio.com/deploy/), either by serving it on your own, or through [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/).

If you run into any code-specific problems feel free to ask another question!